# Is it possible that a continuous function in every point has a discontinuous instantaneous rate at every point?

Tags: calculus

when x changes continuously,so does y.However as x changes continuously, Dy/Dx changes abruptly it goes nuts.

Answer (score 1):

[Weierstrass function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). $f(x)=\sum \frac{1}{2^n}\cos(3^n x)$. Continuous but nowhere differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact that the derivative $f'$ of a differentiable function $f\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ has the Darboux property ( intermediate value property) : if $f'(a) < \xi < f'(b)$ then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c) = \xi$. There is still a lot of freedom in Darboux property.

Check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29 and for extra info
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Darboux_property